# Bootstrap 4 Carousel with solid color in background and Image on right and text on left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

Pardon me if I am asking something silly, but I have a requirement to create a full page slider with solid color as background and some text on left side and an image on right. Something like [Google's Gmail Page](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/).
Currently the result I want is

[image]

I have used Bootstrap 4's Carousel

[image]

I have modified it slightly and made its background grey as its in Google's image. Now I want the text to be left aligned and have a responsive auto resizeable image on the right (Or even if I can have an image adjusted on the top of the text only) which is also responsive when viewed on mobile. Something like

[image].

I am using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StartBootstrap/yezxdwv3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=yezxdwv3) and I have modified the code as

```
<div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #eff0f1">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

<style>
    .carousel-item {
        background-color: #eeeeee; /*Solid grey background*/
        }
    .carousel-caption {
        color: black;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove d-none class from carousel-caption and try this way :

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.text_part{
 display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 575px){
 .text_part{
 display: block;
}
.left_part{
 display: none;
}
}
```

```html
  <section class="text_part">
    <div class="text">
     <h2 >your text</h2>
   </div>
 </section>

 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: gray">
      <div class="carousel-caption  d-md-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 left_part">
            your text
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
           img
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: pink">
      <div class="carousel-caption  d-md-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 left_part">
            your text
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
           img
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: green">
     <div class="carousel-caption  d-md-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 left_part">
            your text
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
           img
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```